# Subclassing UIButton and adding UILabel to the view hierarchy causes currentImage to condense

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I originally wanted to have a blue oval appear upon highlighting the button, with the title centered over that image.

When I set the background image, my blue oval would get stretched out.

When I set the foreground image, the blue oval appeared perfectly, but consequently, that offset my titleLabel to the side, making it look weird.

Instead of bothering with insets, I subclassed UIButton, and added a UILabel to the center of the view using autolayout constraints.

Now when the I press the button, the blue oval appears, but the image is condensed. When I press the button again, the blue oval appears as normal. I find the condensing of the image strange, according to the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIButton):

> Using the Image (currentImage) field, you can specify an image to appear within the content of your button. If the button has a title, this image appears to the left of it, and centered otherwise. The image does not stretch or condense, so make sure to select an image that is the proper size to appear in your button.

When I remove the UILabel from the view hierarchy of the UIButton, then the foreground image looks normal again. What could be causing this?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self configureTextLabel];
}

- (void)configureTextLabel {
    self.textLabel = [UILabel new];
    self.textLabel.text = self.text;
    self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self refreshLabelTextColor];

    [self addSubview:self.textLabel];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.textLabel
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                    multiplier:1.f
                                                      constant:0.f]];

    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self.textLabel
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                    multiplier:1.f
                                                      constant:0.f]];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

    if (self.text != nil) {
        [self refreshLabelTextColor];
    }
}

- (void)refreshLabelTextColor {
    self.textLabel.textColor = self.highlighted ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the way the rendering mode of the image? I set the rendering mode of the image to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal, but that didn't fix it :(

Comment: I don't think what I said in the comment above is relevant, it has more to do with color than anything.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wound up deciding not to subclass UIButton, and revert to using UIButton's foreground image.

The foreground image is no longer being condensed in the UIButton, but I was still having the issue where the number was being offset to the right, instead of being centered over the oval background image.

I decided to use KVO to observe for when the button is highlighted, and adjust the insets of the both the foreground image and the text label. I've provided the code below:

```
- (void)addKeyValueObserversToButtons {
    for (UIButton *button in self.buttons) {
        [button addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted" options:0 context:NULL];
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"highlighted"]) {
        UIButton *button = nil;
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            button = (UIButton *)object;
        }

        UIImage *highlightImage = button.currentImage;
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, button.titleLabel.frame.size.width, 0, 0);
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -highlightImage.size.width, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The reason why I had such a hard time adjusting the insets is because I made the false assumption that the foreground image would always be centered in the button when highlighted.

What ends up happening is that by including the foreground image into the button, it essentially adds on to the width of the text label, and UIButton centers them both as a single entity, taking both widths into account.

That's why the foreground image appeared to be slightly offcentered to the left.

By adding an inset from the left of the foreground image by the width of the text label, and subtracting an inset from the left of the text label by the width of the image, this produced the desired outcome:

a centered image with the text centered over the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler all around to make a private extension of the button which overloads one or a combination of the following `UIButton` methods which already exist and should help you place the image and the label exactly where you need them relative to a given contentRect:

```
class UIButton {

    // these return the rectangle for the background (assumes bounds), the content (image + title) and for the image and title separately. the content rect is calculated based
    // on the title and image size and padding and then adjusted based on the control content alignment. there are no draw methods since the contents
    // are rendered in separate subviews (UIImageView, UILabel)

    open func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect

    open func contentRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect

    open func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect

    open func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect
}
```

See Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton#symbols) under "Getting Dimensions" for more information about these methods.